# How to read HTML from URL.openStream() after 500 return code causes exception?

Tags: java

I'm creating an educational terminal application that is fetching a website via `URL.openStream()`. Based on the query, the page might return a 500 error code. However, there is a valuable error description in the body which I would like to display.

Unfortunately, `URL.openStream()` throws IOException when it encounters the return code 500, and I have no way to read the stream once the exception is caught.

```java
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
  URL url_connection = new URL(url);
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url_connection.openStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

The variable `in` will stay null because the exception is thrown before the openStream returns.

How to read the HTML code from the HTTP response?

Comment: if you look in the API description for URL you can see that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection() will instead return a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html and from this this there are a lot of options how to read the responses.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by using `HttpURLConnection`, which has a method called `getErrorStream()`:

```java
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
try {
  URL url_connection = new URL(url);
  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url_connection.openConnection();
  System.out.println(new String(conn.getInputStream().readAllBytes()));
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(new String(conn.getErrorStream().readAllBytes()));
}
```